# Laravel - how can I return view from another function

Tags: laravel

Route:

```
Route::controller(PublicController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/index', 'index')->name('public.index');
});
```

View:

```
index.blade.php
wrong_browser.blade.php
```

In controller, this way is ok:

```
class PublicController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if(is_wrong_browser)
            return view(public.wrong_browser);
        
        return view('public.index');
    }
}
```

But how can I return view from another function, like this, without making a new route:

```
class PublicController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->CheckBrowser();
        
        return view('public.index');
    }
    
    public function CheckBrowser()
    {
        if(is_wrong_browser)
            return view(public.wrong_browser);
        }
}
```

Comment: what is the issue with the current approach?

Comment: In controller, I wil have more function where I must check if the browser is wrong. This is why I want to make CheckBrowser() - to avoid repeat same code, but I can't return view from here. My questions is if it possible?

Comment: that's what I am asking, what is the issue? You can do this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method redirect.

```
return redirect()->route('index');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#defining-middleware) which you either define [globally](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#global-middleware), or on [specific routes](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware#global-middleware).

```
class CheckUserActive
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // determine value of $is_wrong_browser
        $is_wrong_browser = true;

        if ($is_wrong_browser) {
                return redirect()->route('is-wrong-browser-route');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

It is bad practice to return a view from middleware instead redirect your user to another route.

Alternatively, you could have a base `Controller` that your `Controllers` extend which has the `checkBrowser` function defined on it and the extending `Controllers` therefore have access to:

```
class WrongBrowserController extends \App\Http\Controllers\Controller
{
    public function checkBrowser()
    {
        // determine value of $is_wrong_browser
        $is_wrong_browser = true;

        if ($is_wrong_browser)
        {
            return view('wrong-browser-view');
        }
    }
}


class PublicController extends WrongBrowserController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->checkBrowser();

        return view('index');
    }
}
```